# How to handle suggested edits changing code in answers to deviate from code in the question?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have recently unlocked reviewing suggested edits so I am still getting to grips with the process.

Situation:

I saw an edit changing variable names in a code block, I initially skipped it, the next review task was almost identical and prompted me to hit the back button on my browser to see if I actually did press skip or not (I had) the same user had proposed nearly the same edit to two answers on a single question. I then opened up the question to further see what was going on and noticed the code in the answers was done to match the code in the question. I rejected both edits with the custom message

> The code has been written this way to match the code in the question

I then checked back on the status of the suggestions later on, and saw that one of them another reviewer rejected the edit too but the other one two other reviewers accepted the edit so it went through, I then went to the answer and rolled back the edit.

[First suggestion I saw](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21144282)

[Second suggestion I saw](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21144240)

[Revision History for the first](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33282885/revisions)

This post is not aimed as a call out post, but a learning post for future action.

Comment: Looks like the edits were done just for the sake of it. Suggested edits didn't add any real value to the original post. I believe you reviewed correctly.

Comment: I agree you've rejected correctly, I've previously rolled back edits like this that got approved on my own posts, but I'm not sure you should manually rollback an edit after two people agreed with it, and you were the only one that didn't.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth but if one gets rejected, one gets approved we are sending out mixed messages on if this is correct behaviour

Comment: In such cases, I would rollback the edits first, if it continue than a custom mod flag will handle it.

Comment: This users edits really are a mixed bag. Sometimes totally unnecessary, sometimes at least making the appearance a bit better, sometimes making it worse or not removing the "bad" parts. I can see good intent, but he may need to get a bit of help on "how to make good edits".

Comment: I'd agree with @KamiKaze, I see a lot of incomplete edits, but the editor in question doesn't seem like an edit farmer. I'd guess that the editor was renaming the `_` variables in a misguided attempt to improve code readability (though I agree with the OP here, it's more important to keep code consistency with the question, and the edits should have been rejected). As far as the problems left behind, remember that it might be possible that they aren't comfortable enough with English to fix some of the remaining grammar issues in some content.

Answer (score 8):

> I rejected both edits

You edit rejection was correct in this case. The edits were pretty minor and they didn't provide any clarity or value to the original post. Please continue doing that.

> I then went to the answer and rolled back the edit

I suggest to avoid this going forward. Reason being it may start rollback wars. If it was your own post, rollback would have been fine.

Comment: I would consider a rollback fine as long as you don't allow yourself to get involved in a rollback war. Roll back once. If it gets reverted to the version from which you rolled back: flag for moderator attention and move on.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thats a valid point, I agree. In this particular case, a rollback was probably not needed though.

Answer (score -4):

I think the key here is intent.
If the author is suggesting an edit that doesn't change the intent of the code in question in should be fine.

When it comes to code, there's a lot of different coding standards out there and people work to the standards they have gotten used to over time. That could mean that the code is validly being re-written in a manner that the author feels is an improvement but gut feeling is that it's subjective and you should always use an amount of "common sense" to determine if you feel the edit adds anything to the original posting.

This answer is probably somewhat vague but i feel that the question doesn't warrant a hard fast rule here so I accept that it maybe of varying value depending on interpretation.

Comment: I do not think intent what is the point here, whether or not he was well meaning with the edit does not matter. He made the answer worse by disconnecting it from the question. It is not bad but worse than before.